# cmd2 `cmd1` vs cmd1 | xargs cmd2

Tags: shell-script, pipe, xargs, command-substitution

I'm trying to find a file with `find` and then pass the found path to `sqlite3`. I'm only dropped into the `sqlite>` prompt if my command is of the form:

```
sqlite3 `find . -type f -iname "*.db" | head -n1`
```

But these forms do not work:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.db" | head -n1 | xargs sqlite3
find . -type f -iname "*.db" | head -n1 | xargs -I% sh -c 'sqlite3 %;'
```

Why do the latter commands simply do nothing?

Comment: `dropped into the sqlite> prompt` is expected result of `sqlite3 <db file name>` command. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Alex P. - I am trying to use the second form (with piping) to open a file with `sqlite3`.

Comment: then you have achieved your goal. `sqlite` has opened your file.

Comment: @Alex P. - By "second form" I mean the `... | xargs` example, which does *not* use `sqlite` to open the file and drop me to its prompt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In:

```
... | xargs cmd
```

depending on the implementation, `cmd`'s stdin is either `/dev/null` or that pipe. It cannot be the outer stdin since that is lost because of the piping.

```
$ echo /proc/self/fd/0 | gnu-xargs ls -ld
lr-x------ 1 me me 64 Dec 11 22:04 /proc/self/fd/0 -> /dev/null
$ echo /proc/self/fd/0 | busybox-or-solaris-...-xargs ls -ld
lr-x------    1 me me        64 Dec 11 22:04 /proc/self/fd/0 -> pipe:[99839]
```

In either case, `sqlite3` won't be able to read any input from you.

The:

```
sqlite3 `find . -type f -iname "*.db" | head -n1`
```

command takes the first line of the first file path returned by `find`, splits it according to `$IFS`, performs globbing on those, and passes the resulting words as different arguments to sqlite3. That makes little sense.

With GNU `find` (probably what you're using since you're using `-iname`):

```
sqlite3 "$(find . -type f -iname "*.db" -print -quit)"
```

We use `-exit` to tell `find` to exit after having printed the first found file. We use the modern form of command substitution `$(...)`, and skip the split+glob part (which doesn't make sense) by quoting the command substitution.

You can also use (still GNU specific):

```
find . -type f -iname '*.db' \( -exec sqlite3 {} \; -o -true \) -quit
```

(though you'll loose the exit status of `sqlite3`).

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
sqlite3 ./**/*.(#i)db(D.[1])
```

Comment: So whether or not `cmd` behaves as if invoked directly with an argument (first form in my question) is entirely dependent upon how `cmd` is implemented? Because `... | xargs cmd` works as I expect for various other `cmd` such as (as you demonstrated) `ls`, `xxd`, and `vim`, but not for other `cmd` such as `type`.   So `xargs` is doing something more complicated than can be thought of as string replacement?

Comment: @wes, It works (with all the caveats) with `sqlite3` as well, it's just that `sqlite3` happens to read user input from stdin while `ls` doesn't.